# ml.net anomaly detection not working properly

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I have 99% confidence machinelearning structure on `ml.net`, however it shows wrong anomaly.

I use the below code to detect it:

```
var mlcontext = new MLContext();

            var dataView = mlcontext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(list);

            string outputColumnName = nameof(IidSpikePrediction.Prediction);
            string inputColumnName = nameof(TimeSeriesData.VALUE);

            var transformedData = mlcontext.Transforms.DetectIidSpike(outputColumnName, inputColumnName, 99, list.Count / 4).Fit(dataView).Transform(dataView);

            var predictionColumn = mlcontext.Data.CreateEnumerable<IidSpikePrediction>(transformedData, reuseRowObject: false);
```

Here is the result. 
The count pass to 6 from 5 but it says that this is alert but it is not.

How can we explain this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried different parameters to see if that helps? You can also try using the Model Builder to see what model that provides.

Comment: yes, i changed the values but no luck.

Comment: To me it looks like the `PVALUE` field is being used because there was a spike (`1E-08`) there.